# Calculate Code coverage of C# selenium Test cases

Tags: asp.net, selenium, selenium-webdriver, code-coverage, mstest

I have written test case using Selenium WebDriver in c# and MSTest for Asp .net Application.
Is there any tool available for calclulating code coverage of selenium test cases.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score -1):

Given that you are using C# the Code Coverage tools shipped with Visual Studio will work.

Comment: I am not talking about Unit test case, I am talking about Selenium Automated test cases, which is not same like our mstest unit test cases (which actually test particular layer of our app)

Comment: you mentioned "calclulating code coverage of selenium test cases" for which the standard CC tools work if you write in "c# and MSTest". If not do provide some more data or a sample of your Selenium Automated test case.

Comment: Selenium is use for Automation test case not for our traditional unit test case. so it's understood, i am talking about automated test cases.

Comment: @PavanTiwari is there something stopping you from running your Selenium tests from mstest?  Can you not put them in methods marked with [TestMethod] attribute?